# Image not shrinking when I try max width

Tags: html, css, image

Trying to have my image shrink with the page size. Tried a couple things either it doesn't work or it decides to fit another div I have which isn't related to this one

```
.top-page-image {
    position: relative;
    top: -8px;
    left: -8px;
    background-image: url(basictop.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    opacity: 0.8;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

and the HTML

```
<div class="top-page-image"></div>
```

Comment: I'm not clear what you need to achieve. With the background size set to cover the part of the image shown will adjust to either rop the sides or the top/bottom to make sure its aspect ratio is not affected but that the whole window will be covered. Did you want the whole image to be viewable whatever the viewport aspect ratio instead?

Comment: yeah, want the image to be viewable regardless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the whole image always visible regardless of the viewport's aspect ratio use contain instead of cover as the background-size.

Also set background-repeat to no-repeat and you may want to ensure it is centered.

Inevitably you will have space either at the sides or top/bottom if the aspect ratio of the viewport isn't the same as the aspect ratio of the image.

```css
.top-page-image {
  position: relative;
  top: -8px;
  left: -8px;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/300);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  opacity: 0.8;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-page-image"></div>
```

Comment: This helped thank you. But how will I now go about fixing the spaces on the sides kind of confused on how to deal with that part

Comment: How do you mean 'fixing the spaces'? If the image is sort of long and thin compared to the viewport there will just be blank space on either side of the image.

Comment: Now when I shrink the page the image doesn't fit the whole screen anymore. The image shrinks but it doesn't fit the whole screen and leaves white spaces all over

Comment: It shouldn't be leaving white spaces all over, only either on the sides or on the top and the bottom. You cannot avoid having white space if you want the whole of the image to show.

Answer (score 0):

### It is the same as you want. If it is not what you won't try to describe your problem clearly by using code attribute in the text editor

```css
.top-page-image {
    position: relative;
    top: -8px;
    left: -8px;
    background-image: url(https://cdn.dribbble.com/uploads/601/original/ff7474bc9245e3ac5a25cff4f39b2707.png?1544835635);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    opacity: 0.8;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-page-image"></div>
```